# Why is my website not getting loaded in Internet Explorer?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, browser, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, incompatibility

Recently I tried to host my website in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The website got up and running and now I can access it using Chrome and Mozilla. However, it is giving me the following error while opening it using Microsoft Edge.

[image: Microsoft Edge console output]

This is the output that I am getting with Mozilla and Chrome where the website is running perfectly.

[image: Mozrilla output.]

Can somebody explain why the site is not running in Edge?

Comment: Please post your text output as text, not images

Comment: I think you need to reset IE setting

Answer (score 2):

**Angular CLI applications require a few more steps in order to support Internet Explorer.**
*It’s really simple: un-comment a few imports and install a couple of npm packages.*
We see this error because there are a lot of commonly used parts of JavaScript that Internet Explorer just doesn’t support. This is especially true for array functions.

1. Un-comment some imports in the polyfill.ts file
2. Install a couple of npm packages.
   First open the file in your IDE or text editor: ie-test\src\polyfills.ts

Un-comment all the import lines in there. For me, the easy way is just to replace all
// import 
with 
**

```html
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'classlist.js';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

> Install npm Pacakages

1. npm install --save classlist.js
2. npm install --save web-animations-js

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

Reset the IE settings

1) In Internet Explorer, select the Tools menu and then click Internet Options.

2) Click the Advanced tab, Click Reset button.

3) Click the Reset button while a prompt asks ”Are you sure you want to reset all the Internet Explorer settings?”.

4) Click OK, restart your IE.

Then check your issue

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Trying this out will be a bit difficult as the advanced settings for the IE is managed by the administrators at my company.So they can't be reset. Is there anything else that i can try.