# Internet explorer & Angular 6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular6, internet-explorer-11

I am getting issue while using angular 6 and IE 11, app is working fine in chrome & another browser but in internet explorer, i am getting this

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk
>   default~app-xxxxx~eb5ba6d4
>   failed. (missing: http://localhost:4200/default~app-xxxx.js) Error:
>   Loading chunk default~app-xxxx~eb5ba6d4 failed. (missing:
>   http://localhost:4200/default~app-xxxx~eb5ba6d4.js)

Project details

Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

### Package                      Version

> @angular-devkit/architect    0.8.3 
>   @angular-devkit/core         0.8.3
>   @angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.3 
>   @schematics/angular          0.8.3
>   @schematics/update           0.8.3 
>   rxjs                         6.2.2
>   typescript                   2.9.2

My app routing is

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:  'app/content/pages/pages.module#PagesModule'

    },
    {
        path: 'layout',
        loadChildren: 'app/content/layout/layout.module#LayoutModule',      
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    }
];
```

Comment: do you see anything (like a 404) in the dev console's network tab?

Comment: @Arikael no nothing to see like 404

Comment: what is the http status of the file? Or do you see nothing at all?
We once had the problem that some AdBlocker interfered

Comment: Try to update the related packages, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investing some hours finally found my solutions
Issue about promise((t,n) => ,

1. At first, open the src/polyfills.ts file, and uncomment

> ```
> /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
> // import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
> // import 'core-js/es6/object';
> // import 'core-js/es6/function';
> // import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
> // import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
> // import 'core-js/es6/number';
> // import 'core-js/es6/math';
> // import 'core-js/es6/string';
> // import 'core-js/es6/date';
> // import 'core-js/es6/array';
> // import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
> // import 'core-js/es6/map';
> // import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
> // import 'core-js/es6/set';
> ```

=> lambda expression does not support in IE so we can replace with code function() instead of this expression.

2. Install some packages

   npm install --save web-animations-js

   npm install --save classlist.js

Then i was found promise issue from one of the npm package (fuctbase64/index.js)

```
module.exports = function (event) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let files = event.target.files;
    let len = files.length;
    if (len > 1) {
      reject(new DOMException("Only one file can be uploaded at a time"));
    } else {
      reader.onerror = () => {
        reader.abort();
        reject(new DOMException("Problem parsing input file."));
      };
      let file = files[0]
      reader.onload = (evt) => {
        const uint = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
        let bytes = [];
        uint.map(byte => {
          bytes.push(byte.toString(16));
        });
        const hex = bytes.join('').toUpperCase();
        let base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        file.base64 = base64;
        file.binaryFileType = getMimetype(hex);
        resolve(file);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  });
}
```

Replace code with

```
module.exports = function (event) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let files = event.target.files;
    let len = files.length;
    if (len > 1) {
      reject(new DOMException("Only one file can be uploaded at a time"));
    } else {
      reader.onerror = function() {
        reader.abort();
        reject(new DOMException("Problem parsing input file."));
      };
      let file = files[0]
      reader.onload = function(evt){
        const uint = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
        let bytes = [];
        uint.map(function(byte) {
          bytes.push(byte.toString(16));
        });
        const hex = bytes.join('').toUpperCase();
        let base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        file.base64 = base64;
        file.binaryFileType = getMimetype(hex);
        resolve(file);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: > lambda expression does not support in IE, maybe you can change som settings in your tsconfig.json-file instead to fix this: `"module": "es2015"`, and `"target":"es5"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add some polyfills. If you open the `src/polyfills.ts` file, you need to uncomment these imports:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

**EDIT:**

There might be more polyfils listed below this list, as mentioned by @Arikael in the comments, that you might want to uncomment as well.

Comment: below these lines there is `/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';` 

Did you uncomment this too?

Comment: @Arikael yes "core-js/es6/reflect" already uncommented but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to add meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the steps from this?
[this was the issue with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999709/why-is-my-website-not-getting-loaded-in-internet-explorer/55000554#55000554)

Angular CLI applications require a few more steps in order to support Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I am new at angular. I have faced an error about "loading chunk xyz module failed" in Internet Explorer. I had tried lots of things but no solution.
Finally I changed adding order of "declarations" array and "imports" array in NgModule definition. 
I mean defining "declarations" before "imports" in NgModule() solved my problem.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translateHttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> This happens if a chunk could not be loaded, which will happen more often on mobile due to poor connections. You need to have some error handling in case a chunk failed to load, such as asking the user to reload the page.

[ref](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7502#issuecomment-439360421)